# Laravel 5.3 Throttle Login When Using JWT Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

I am using JWT for my Laravel + Angular application. I see Laravel 5.3 has login throttling feature out of the box. But how can I get this to work when using JWT Auth? I have the following code but the login throttling is not working. Inspite of numerous failed attempts, I only get the `Invalid Login Details` error but its not throttling and showing `Too many logins` error:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
     use AuthenticatesUsers;

     protected $maxLoginAttempts=5;
     protected $lockoutTime=300;

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
      $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

      $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
      ]);

      if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Too many logins'], 400);
      }

      try {
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
          return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid Login Details'], 401);
        }
      } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Could Not Create Token'], 500);
      }

      // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
      return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}
```

How do you use this feature using using JWTAuth? Can you someone help me out please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're JWTAuth is not throwing exception to increment your login attempt. Simply put `$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);` inside condition for auth failing like so:

```
if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid Login Details'], 401);
}
```

Comment: thank you @Rafal for your reply and good point. I added the increment inside login attempt, but its still only showing `Invalid Login Details` error message even after failed attempts.

Comment: What cache are you using, does it work properly? RateLimiter is using cache so that could be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, are you referring to cache driver? I have it set as `CACHE_DRIVER=array`. Also would using JWT instead of the default Auth be the reason for not working?

Comment: _array - sessions are stored in a simple PHP array and will not be persisted across requests._ that's why it does not work. Change cache to some request-persistable like native session or memcache

Comment: Thank you @Rafal I left it as array since the app is still in my mac's mamp which doesnt have memcache installed. I will see if I can install memcache and try that. Thank you for the pointer. I will accept your answer now and will report back if I had any luck. Thanks for your reply. Pardon my ignorance, what is the native session for cache? If I dont have memcache or redis in my pc, what can I set for Cache_DRIVER?

Comment: I changed the `CACHE_DRIVER` to `file` and its working! Awesome!! You were spot on with my mistake. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped! I recommend to use array cache only for testing purposes.

Comment: Got it. Cheers!! In my live server, I will be setting up memcache for this.